# "The author is by Katherine Patterson" — what is the term for the error in this sentence?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

I am marking some student work and one of the sentences was

> The author is by Katherine Patterson.

What is the term for the error in this sentence?

Comment: Which is the error? _The **book** is by KP_ is fine: wrong word/word choice error. _The author is KP_ is fine: misused preposition: "**by**".

Comment: It is usually called 'just plain wrong', a 'grammatical error' or, more obscurantistly, a 'solecism'.

Comment: Do you think you can give us more information--what error was made? Depending, your student either a) meant 'book' and not 'author or b) added in an extra word 'by'. That would be more helpful for identifying the term you're looking for.

Comment: Not everything has a name. You can just say what the correction should be.

Answer (score 6):

You *could* call it a conflation error.  It sounds like the student wanted to say either:

> The book is by Katherine Patterson.

or:

> The author is Katherine Patterson.

but simply conflated the two simple sentences into one:

> The author is by Katherine Patterson.

As a side note, not all conflation creates an error.  For example, Peter Shor gave a nice example of a conflated idiom in his answer to [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/33589/what-is-the-origin-of-the-phrase-stand-on-your-head-and-spit-wooden-nickels). [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conflation) has an entire entry on *conflation*.

Answer (score 1):

It’s either an extra word, or the wrong word.  There is no special name for it.

- The book is by Katherine Patterson.
- The author is Katherine Patterson.

Comment: Yes, "extra" or "extraneous" is the right way to go.

Answer (score 0):

The term *Katherine Patterson* is a [predicate nominative](http://www.grammaruntied.com/blog/?p=729).
The predicate is equivalent to the subject, *author*. The correct construction is

> The author is Katherine Patterson.

The construction *by Katherine Patterson* is a prepositional phrase that would usually serve as an adjective or adverb.

It can't be an adjective modifying the subject. The author is equivalent to the named person, not characterized by the person.

It can't modify the verb *is*.  The author *is* not *by* anyone or anything.

If the subject were *book*, the phrase could be adverbial, modifying *is*, defining the source of the book's existence.

> The *book* is by Katherine Patterson.

If the subject were *book*, the phrase could, arguably, be adjectival, meaning

> The book, by Katherine Patterson, is.

Comment: What about "The book is by Katherine Patterson." That seems straightforward, and plenty correct.

Comment: @J.R. The sixth paragraph refers to just that, even though it does not list it. I will edit to make it clear. And +1 for *conflation error*.

Comment: Strong the force is...